# I have an issue with BleachBit which is displaying an error

Tags: 20.04, python, wine, bleachbit

Im using ubuntu 20.04. I was playing with Wine trying to run a certain game (but failed). i tried my best to clean my system up by uninstalling all the apt-get i did, and undoing all the the PPA's.

When I was done, I wanted to run BleachBit, but its now showing an error.

Can someone help me out.

```
Error when checking for updates: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/bleachbit/bleachbit/GUI.py", line 1160, in check_online_updates
    updates = Update.check_updates(options.get('check_beta'),
  File "/usr/share/bleachbit/bleachbit/Update.py", line 155, in check_updates
    opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', user_agent())]
  File "/usr/share/bleachbit/bleachbit/Update.py", line 87, in user_agent
    dist = platform.dist()
AttributeError: module 'platform' has no attribute 'dist'
```

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahqOe.png)

Edit:

I've uninstalled and reinstalled BleachBit, but that didnt help.

These are some of the commands I've used during my Wine 'saga':

```
sudo apt install wine64
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt install wine64 wine32
sudo apt-get install winbind
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:commendsarnex/winedri3
sudo apt install mesa wine2.0
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa
sudo apt full-upgrade 
sudo apt install mesa-utils
wget http://dl.winehq.org/wine/wine-gecko/2.47.1/wine-gecko-2.47.1-x86_64.msi
sudo wine msiexec /i wine-gecko-2.47.1-x86_64.msi
wget https://dl.winehq.org/wine/wine-gecko/2.47.1/wine-gecko-2.47.1-x86_64.msi
sudo wine msiexec /i wine-gecko-2.47.1-x86_64.msi
sudo apt remove mesa-utils
sudo ppa-purge ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa
sudo install ppa-purge
sudo apt install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa
sudo ppa-purge focal ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa <--- canceled this to add '-d'
sudo ppa-purge -d focal ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa
```

> “True ignorance is not the absence of knowledge, but the refusal to acquire it.”

Comment: I will try, im really a noob and new to this space. So not 100% sure what you are asking of me.

Comment: How can I find the outputs, each command gave at the time?

Comment: As you run them, keep a log or edit your question to include those details. Can you edit your question to update us on the problem you are currently experiencing, after having done all of these actions? You mentioned earlier that you thought python was messed up, but you removed that. What is the problem right now?

Comment: I have reinstalled Ubuntu20.04. Im now keeping my system backed-up with TimeShift.

BleachBit gave the same error on my newly installed ubuntu installation. So my conclussion is now that the 2 python scripts of BleachBit, which BleachBit sees errors in. Are real errors in the script it self, nothing to do with my system.

Comment: What python scripts? Are you not using the `bleachbit` package in Ubuntu repositories? If you need to report a bug with Ubuntu software: https://askubuntu.com/q/5121

Comment: @Nmath Ive added the picture/screenshot in, that shows the issue I see in BleachBit. It reffers to 3 lines in 2 different Pythin scripts BleachBit uses to look for updates

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed a year ago as [issue 819](https://github.com/bleachbit/bleachbit/issues/819) for release BleachBit 4.0.0, but Ubuntu has a "no rolling release policy," so Ubuntu 20.04 will always have BleachBit 3.9.0 beta.

Please [download the latest BleachBit](https://www.bleachbit.org/download) (currently 4.4.0) from the official site. I recommend always using latest version on this site.

I am the author.